# added-by-click rectangle dissapear in canvas fiddle html5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding a rectangle by click inside of a canvas, to start writing a text...

**PROBLEM**

once I start writing the text
the rectangle dissapear.I think the problem is that I dont pass any value of the new rectangle to the function....how would I solve this? or maybe activate a rectangle set by default once I click on `add text`

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/26337/

**EXAMPLE** edited to add the basic problem only.

```js
$("#Add").on("click", function() {
  $("#first_text").show();
  $("#resetInput").show();
  var rheight = 20;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#E1FFC7';
  ctx.fillRect(20, rheight, 300, 50);

});





var canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


// core drawing function
var drawMe = function() {
  var img = document.getElementById('bg');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 364, 662, 0, 0, 364, 662);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#E1FFC7';


  text = $("#first_text").val();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillText(text, 20, 20)


}




$("#resetInput").on("click", function() {

  $("#first_text").val("");
  drawMe();
});

$("#first_text").on("change keypress keyup keydown ", function() {


  drawMe();
});





drawMe();
```

```css
canvas {
  margin: 40px;
}

#first_text,
#resetInput {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</p>
<button id="Add">add text</button>
<br/>

<input type="text" id="first_text"> <button id="resetInput">reset</button>


<br>
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
<img id="bg" src="https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/398893/15136779/4e765036-1639-11e6-9201-67e728e86f39.jpg" style="opacity:0;" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you call `drawMe` from your keyboard input, you are drawing ontop of what is already there, thus drawing on top of the green box.

You need to add this after you set your color within the `drawMe` function:

```
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 300, 50);
```

Here is a working example:

```js
$("#Add").on("click", function() {
  $("#first_text").show();
  $("#resetInput").show();
  var rheight = 20;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#E1FFC7';
  ctx.fillRect(20, rheight, 300, 50);
});

var canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// core drawing function
var drawMe = function() {
  var img = document.getElementById('bg');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 364, 662, 0, 0, 364, 662);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#E1FFC7';
  if ($('#first_text:visible').length > 0) {
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 300, 50);
  }

  text = $("#first_text").val();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillText(text, 20, 20)
}

$("#resetInput").on("click", function() {
  $("#first_text").val("");
  drawMe();
});

$("#first_text").on("change keypress keyup keydown ", function() {
  drawMe();
});

drawMe();
```

```css
canvas {
  margin: 40px;
}

#first_text,
#resetInput {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</p>
<button id="Add">add text</button>
<br/>

<input type="text" id="first_text"> <button id="resetInput">reset</button>


<br>
<canvas id="cv"></canvas>
<img id="bg" src="https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/398893/15136779/4e765036-1639-11e6-9201-67e728e86f39.jpg" style="opacity:0;" />
```

Comment: ok.what if I want to add another rectangle below? maybe `fillrect(20,140`,..besides its supposed the canvas start empty without green rectangle inside

Comment: yeah, you would just call it like that `ctx.fillRect(20, height + offset, 300, 50);`

Comment: how do I start the canvas cleared? and add the rectangle only after click?

Comment: You can use `ctx.clearRect()` to clear an area of the canvas

Comment: Every time there is a change to some sort of data, you will need to redraw the entire canvas.

Comment: could you edit your answer using this new information pls?

Comment: I have updated the answer, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm always using the rect that is already within the function